# Configure / Change JQuery AJAX Encoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a basic PATCH call like this one:

```
.ajax({
    url: "/foo/bar/"
    type: "PATCH",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        "foo": "foosball",
        "bar": "bars on bars"
    },
    ...
});
```

Jquery automatically encodes the data, which leaves "bars on bars" like "bars+on+bars". Is there a way to change the encoding so that spaces are replaces with %20 rather than pluses?

I've noticed this [thread](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3400) that didn't seem to lead anywhere.

I've also taken note of `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent` but haven't gotten either to work. Both seem to result in the string being double encoded, leaving me with `bars%2520on%2520bars`

*summary*:

What I start with:
... "bars on bars" ...

What the received data looks like after jquery encodes the request:
"bars+on+bars"

What I need the received data to look like:
"bars%20on%20bars"

Comment: How about `"bar": encodeURIComponent("bars on bars")` ?

Comment: For some reason that double encodes it and leaves me with `bars%2520on%2520bars`

Comment: What are u using PATCH for ? How you access on url page

Comment: The endpoint accepts PATCH requests. Does jquery encode differently for different http methods?

Comment: Yeah, because double encode here: `space` -> `%20`, and then `%20` -> `%2520`. Maybe you can process data manually and set  `processData: false`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `processData: false` requires the data to be a string, which is less than ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still wish there was a better way, but I ended up using this plugin from this [website](http://rohanradio.com/blog/2011/02/22/posting-json-with-jquery/).

```
 jQuery.extend({
     postJSON: function(url, data, callback) {
         return jQuery.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: url,
             data: JSON.stringify(data),
             success: callback,
             dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json",
             processData: false
         });
      }
  });
```

This forces my api to parse the body as a string into a dict/json. Hopefully in a few years someone can come along with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about use a variable and pass that to data.

```
var d={
    "foo": "foosball",
    "bar": "bars on bars"
}
d.bar=encodeURI(d.bar);

.ajax({
url: "/foo/bar/"
type: "PATCH",
dataType: 'json',
data: d,
...
});
```

Comment: I updated the question, but `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent` double encodes the data, which leaves me with `bars%2520on%2520bars`.

Comment: have you tried adding contentType: application/json ?

Comment: Yes, still pluses though :(

Comment: shooting in the dark... data: JSON.stringify({"foo": "foosball","bar": "bars on bars"})

Comment: Yes, I've been looking at that and I think I might just have to use that. It requires converting it from a string to a dict/json once received though.